# Saving PlayerPrefs on external file for web synchronization

Tags: c#, serialization, unity-game-engine, save, unityscript

As far as I know Playerprefs can be used to store small amount of data on the users PC, like his in-game-name, highscores, current level etc. I want the playerprefs to persist when the user logs in from another device. What I want to do is serialize, encrypt and store all the data from the playerprefs file onto a external file (say config.dat) which I can upload and download from my web server.

An example scenario would be something like this .. The player logs in to his account on android device, config.dat file gets downloaded onto the device, decrypted, deserialized and saved as playerprefs on the device. So everything from current level, highscores and even game states are restored. When the user closes the application, all the current playerprefs get serialized, encrypted, saved onto disk as config.dat and sent back to my web server(mongodb used for database). So when the user again logs in from his iPhone, the config.dat file gets restored and everything is restored exactly as it was on the android device.

I hope the question is clear enough, I searched the interwebs and found a couple of references but nothing substantial. These might help
[Link1](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/253852/saving-player-prefs-external-external-storage-perm.html)
[Link 2](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/216830/can-i-use-playerprefs-to-save-the-best-score-over.html)

Question: How do I serialize and save Playerprefs onto a external file ?

Comment: You can create a JSON or XML file with your playerprefs, than save it on device using System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes or directly send it to your webserver. In between you can encypt/decrypt it. Also take a look at [Application.persistentDataPath](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html)